# Why am I getting an overflow here for unsigned long long

Tags: c++

I am doing something like this

```
unsigned long long r = 1 << 35;;
std::cout << r;
```

and the result I get is 0.
I read that `unsigned long long` is 8 bytes or 64 bits

Comment: `1 << 35` uses `int` precision. You want `1ULL << 35`.